# Music Background service bug when app killed

Tags: android, service, audio-player, android-music-player

I am playing the music and i want to play it in background also but there is a bug that when i kill the app music restarts and also i checked with some toast that oncreate method of service class is called again , how should i do that

```
public class MyMusicService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public MyMusicService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"oncreate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (mediaPlayer!= null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }

        mediaPlayer =MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);


    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"start",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mediaPlayer.start();

         return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"destroy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();


    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: how you started MyMusicService?

Comment: @MikeM. all that won't work

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers yes i have

Comment: The service is restarting means you have made it STICKY. Just remove that and will work as normal.